# How does overflow hidden influence images position in salient theme?

Tags: html, css, themes

***This salient theme***: http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-frostwave/

The question is pretty simple, but for some reason i just cannot understand what combination of css rules makes this thing happen. There are of course other ways to do it, but at this point it drives me insane, that i can't figure it out.

If i remove overflow:hidden from .video-wrap class, video in slider shifts down and at the same time if overflow:hidden is present it shifts up.

What surprises me is how overflow:hidden property can at all influence positioning of elements?

*Thanks in advance. Hope it's a simple question and i am just being stupid.*

Answer (score 0):

Wow you got me really excited too :)

So the answer is really simple. While the website seems to use the background image partially what you see when you load the website is actually just the video element, not the img element. Therefore the overflow: hidden influences only the video. My guess is that the image is some kind of fallback. Try deleting the video element and see what you get...

You can see the video here:

http://43eb74ada891f0f09679-c04bb4ac5bb47a13c85d2a60607693e6.r18.cf2.rackcdn.com/compressed/mountains2_converted.webm?id=4365

Comment: Sorry, i meant the video, not the image.  
Of course image is a fallback for mobile phones. But why and how overflow influences position of a video element is still a mystery to me.

Basically if i mimic this video element behavior, i end up having a dynamic position top, because if i just set top position static to -100px for example, on smaller width screen because i guess dimensions and ratio change, then video goes too much up or down, but in their example it kind of stays the same.

And they don't have dynamic position, instead it somehow done with overflow and position...

Comment: Oh this is a bit too complex for me. All I found out was that with overflow: hidden set the whole video gets centered inside the video-wrap element. Without overflow: hidden it is positioned at the top, causing the effect.This makes sense, but for some reason I wasn't able to reproduce it...

Comment: I see. Anyway thanks for the attempt =). I kind of gave up, and did it with dynamic position top. And maybe someday someone will explain this magic to me.